# Given a set of intervals $(I_n)_n$ contained in $[0, L]$, compute the longest interval in $[0, L]$ which has empty intersection with all $(I_n)_n$

Tags: search-trees, counting, intervals

Let be $(I_n)_n$ a set of $p$ intervals each contained in $[0, L]$ for $L \geq 1$.

I define $(J_n = [a_n, b_n])_n$ the set of intervals which have empty intersection with $I_n$ for all $n \in [[1, p]]$.

I'd like to efficiently compute $\max_n (b_n - a_n + 1)$.

A basic idea I'd try would be to:

(1) Create a segment tree for $(I_n)_n$ in $O(p \ln p)$

(2) Iterate over $[0, L]$ and count the longest line before encountering an interval covered by $(I_n)_n$ (resetting the "max value" to 0 until the next of a certain $J_q$)

Which could give me an algorithm in $O(L + p \ln p)$, the problem is that $L$ is really big in my instances, I'd like to have an algorithm which does not depend on $L$.

Comment: That doesn't uniquely define the $J$ intervals; there will typically be multiple ways to choose $J$ intervals that don't intersect with the $I$ intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(From your notations, I assume the intervals are all discrete as otherwise some of the $J_n$ would not be closed. Furthermore, the length of the intervals would not be $b_n-a_n+1$ so I'm fairly certain that assumption is safe. If however that was not your intention, it should be straightforward enough to adapt the algorithm to the continuous case).

1. Consider all intervals $(I_n=[\![s_n,e_n]\!])_{0\leq n<p}$, and sort them by increasing start time $s_n$, breaking ties arbitrarily  **[time $\mathcal{O}(p\cdot \log p)$]**
2. Build a stack containing only the first interval (i.e. the one with the smallest start). For each subsequent interval: if [the interval doesn't overlap with the head of the stack] then [push it] else [merge it with the head of the stack] **[time $\mathcal{O}(p)$]**

*What we've done here is merge the intervals $(I_n)_n$ so as to rewrite $\bigcup I_n$ as an ordered stack of disjoint intervals. We shall call these intervals $(\tilde{I}_n=[\![\tilde{s}_n,\tilde{b}_n]\!])_n$*

Now iterate linearly through the stack to find the largest interval separating two successive intervals on the stack (without forgetting the two intervals $[\![0,\tilde{s}_0[\![$ and $]\!]\tilde{s}_{-1},L]\!]$) **[time $\mathcal{O}(p)$]**

Overall the runtime is $\mathcal{O}(p\cdot \log p)$.

Comment: I didn't prove correction of the algorithm but it should be straightforward: steps 1 and 2 are fairly well-known (you should be able to find them by looking for 'merging overlapping intervals problem').

Comment: Definitely, the intervals were discrete, thank you for making the assumption.